# What happened to the murder charges in 'Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny'?

Tags: plot-explanation, indiana-jones, indiana-jones-and-dial-of-destiny

In one of the early scenes in "Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny", Dr Voller's Nazi thugs kill two teachers in Hunter College, after which they chase Indiana Jones across New York City. Soon after, we learn that Dr Jones is wanted by the police for their murder. He immediately leaves the country for Tangiers and the rest of the plot.

In the last scene of the film, Indiana Jones wakes up in his New York City apartment and is reunited with his estranged wife, Marion. Everything seems to be "back to normal" at this point: Indy has his wounds all bandaged up, Marion is back and seems to be receptive to them making up, Helena Shaw and Teddy are happy and go out for ice cream. And yet -- the last we knew of the state of things in New York, Indy is being charged with two counts of murder.

**What happened to the murder charges?**

Comment: This probably needs some spoiler tags but I honestly couldn't figure out how to do it without sticking the whole question behind the tags except for the first clause and the last sentence. Hopefully the title is deterrent enough.

Comment: [Is Indy still wanted for murder?](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/IndianaJonesAndTheDialOfDestiny#:~:text=Is%20Indy%20still%20wanted%20for%20murder%3F%C2%A0)

Comment: Hovering shows me that's a tvtropes link. I know better than to click on those!

Answer (score 1):

### They were most likely dropped.

The only reason Indy is accused of murder is because it would be a way to get him arrested and therefore bring him under the control of the government (which is initially supporting Dr Voller). The not-so-ex-Nazi has promised the USA a new weapon, hence he is under the protection of the government (he wasn't the first - read about the [Operation Paperclip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Paperclip)). But once Voller killed his "handler" and showed his true colours, there would be no need to try to detain Jones.

Answer (score -3):

Because Voller died in the past, nothing he did after dying in the plane crash would have happened in the future. So, Indiana Jones would not have been accused of any murders, they didn't happen. Voller was not around to try to get the Dial. The astronauts would have had to get to the moon without his planning. The people at Hunter College would not have been killed.